# Split list into array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a problem to split array into array, here the source code and the output,

```
import numpy as np

s = np.array([[100], [200], [300], [400], [500]])
mean = np.mean(s)
stdev = s.std()
for i in range(len(s)):
    z = ((s[i]-mean)/stdev)
    print z
```

out :

```
[-1.41421356]
[-0.70710678]
[ 0.]
[ 0.70710678]
[ 1.41421356]
```

I want the output like this :

```
[[-1.41421356]
[-0.70710678]
[ 0.]
[ 0.70710678]
[ 1.41421356]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty list and then append the results to that empty list.

```
import numpy as np
s = np.array([[100], [200], [300], [400], [500]])
mean = np.mean(s)
stdev = s.std()
x = []
for i in range(len(s)):
    x.append(((s[i]-mean)/stdev))
print np.array(x)
```

Comment: Thx for your answer Avinash Raj, :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
...
...
z = []

for i in range(len(s)):

    z.append((s[i]-mean)/stdev)

print z
```